# Template MastersDoctoralThesis doesn't recognize the current babel dictionary: "Undefined control sequence. \begin{document}"

Tags: babel, templates

I would like to use the [Template MastersDoctoralThesis](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis) unfortunately it creates an error message which I am not able to debug. The main structure of this template is a main.tex file which calls a class MastersDoctoralThesis.cls.

When I select in the options of the document-class a language, say ngerman, the following way:

```
\documentclass[
11pt, % The default document font size, options: 10pt, 11pt, 12pt
ngerman, % ngerman for German, english for English
singlespacing, % Single line spacing, alternatives: onehalfspacing or doublespacing not load the hyperref package
headsepline, % Uncomment to get a line under the header
]{MastersDoctoralThesis} % The class file specifying the document structure
```

It gives the following messages:
`Error: Undefined control sequence. \begin{document}` ,
`Warning: file 'translations-basic-dictionary-german.trsl' does not appear to be a dictionary`

When I change the language to `english,` than the error remains but the warning changes to
`Warning: file` translations-basic-dictionary-english.trsl' does not appear to be a dictionary`

When I am not using the option in the documentclass at all and simply pass `\RequirePackage[english,ngerman]{babel}` in the MastersDoctoralThesis.cls. I receive:
`Error: Undefined control sequence. \begin{document}`,
`Error: Undefined control sequence. \begin{document}`,
`Warning: file` translations-basic-dictionary-german.trsl' does not appear to be a dictionary`,` Warning: file `translations-basic-dictionary-english.trsl' does not appear to be a dictionary`

Accidentally, I forgot most of the time till now the `,` after the language which strangely worked, till now when I wanted to use the commands in the  class which rely on that option as well. These basically change the descriptions in the document.

The problem occurs independently of the compiler Latex, Lualatex and PDFLatex

Please, help me find to solution.

SvA

**Edit:**
In the log-file the interesting part looks like this:

```
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/psnfss/t1ppl.fd"
File: t1ppl.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for T1/ppl.
)
! Undefined control sequence.
\@trnslt@check@dictionary #1#2->\AddToHook 
                                           {file/after/#1-\@trnslt@language ...
l.90 \begin{document}
                   
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


Package translations Warning: file `translations-basic-dictionary-english.trsl' 
does not appear to be a dictionary on input line 90.


(D:/Users/user/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/tex/latex/translations/dicts/tran
slations-basic-dictionary-english.trsl
File: translations-basic-dictionary-english.trsl (english translation file `tran
slations-basic-dictionary')
)
```

**Edit 2:**

Now, I checked, whether it maybe is an issue with my language styles. I created two minimal examples of documents applying the classes `scrreprt` and `MastersDoctoralThesis`. The first one works fine, the second throws the error again.

Comment: If you download the template into a completely fresh folder and run it, does the error remain?

Comment: the tex error message will show which command is undefined, it will not be `undefined command \begin{document}` that is a totally useless "summary" generated by your editor (is that texstudio?)

Comment: If not, delete all auxiliary files.

Comment: Yes, I use TexStudio.

Comment: ... And I tried it again with a fresh downloaded and un-zipped version from the link given above.

Comment: I the log it says the undefined control sequence is: ```\@trnslt@check@dictionary #1#2->\AddToHook 
                                           {file/after/#1-\@trnslt@language ...```

Comment: Please [edit] your post and paste the error message there.  I don't believe `#` should show up in an error message.

Comment: Only a detail, but there seems to be comma missing in your document class options, after ‘not load the hyperref package’ before ‘headlinesep’

Comment: Thanks for the comment Markus, I will make it more clear. This part is just part of the commends. It is not an option.

Comment: If you download the template again intoa fresh folder, does the error persist?

Comment: Hi Johannes_B, yes the error remains. I used a fresh download, which I unpacked in a separate folder, and I can reproduce the error.

Comment: The most likely explanation for this error is that your LaTeX version is too old for `\AddToHook`. (If you can show us the full `.log` file, we could check if that is indeed the case.) Update your system in Admin and User mode to make sure that all packages are updated properly.

Comment: I had the same problem. I solved it by accessing the MiKTeX Console, and updating all packages under the Updates tab.